# MathJax not rending in production mode

Tags: reactjs, mathjax

I have installed the [better-react-mathjax](https://github.com/fast-reflexes/better-react-mathjax) library to a react project, to aid me with latex, but it doesn't render in production mode, there's no errors in the console nor a warning message, see the snipped below:

```js
{questions[currentQuestionIndex] && (
  <Fragment>
    <Text
      size="xl"
      mb="md"
      mt="md"
      color={'white'}
      className={isLoading ? `hidden` : `shown`}
    >
      <MathJax>
        {`${questions[currentQuestionIndex].number}. ${questions[currentQuestionIndex].description}`}
      </MathJax>
    </Text>
    {!isLoading && questions[currentQuestionIndex].figureUrl && (
      <Image
        className={isLoading ? `hidden` : `shown`}
        alt=""
        hidden={!questions[currentQuestionIndex].figureUrl}
        radius="md"
        src={questions[currentQuestionIndex].figureUrl}
      />
    )}
  </Fragment>
)}
```

in development mode:

[image]

However it does not when I deploy it to vercel:

[image]

Any idea of how can I fix this?

I've tried checking the `latex` markup, whether the latex files and the font is loaded and see if other components on the page have the same issue and surprisingly some parts of the page are rendered, see the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: The only way to truly help with troubleshooting is to share a MCVE, since it is not possible to tell from the code alone why MathJax fails in production: have you tried recreating it on code sandbox, for example? Are you sure that the cache on production is not stale?

Comment: If the math is loaded dynamically into the component you have to add the `dynamic` flag to the relevant `MathJax` component. Otherwise the content will only be typeset once when the component mounts. This setting is automatically turned on when running a dev server locally to accommodate for changes in the code via hot reload; otherwise a full page reload would be necessary every time the source code was updated. Check https://github.com/fast-reflexes/better-react-mathjax for more info about dynamic content.

Answer (score 1):

I just had exactly the same problem and apparently there are props such as 'inline' & 'dynamic' on the  component which after setting to true seem to have resolved the issue for me.

It probably has something to do with resetting the typeset [explained here](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html)

```
<MathJax className='formula' inline dynamic> 
  {steps[currentStep].functionToShow}
</MathJax>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { MathJax, MathJaxContext } from 'better-react-mathjax'

const config = {
    loader: { load: ['input/asciimath'] },
    asciimath: {
        displaystyle: true,
        delimiters: [
            ['$', '$'],
        ]
    }
}
const PreviewMaths = (props) => {
    const { sentence, show } = props
    const mathJaxRef = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (mathJaxRef?.current) {
            mathJaxRef?.current?.typeset()
        }
    }, [sentence])
   
    return (
        <>
            {!show && <center><h3>Preview</h3></center>}
            {sentence && <MathJaxContext config={config}>
                <pre style={{ marginBottom: 0, overflow: 'unset' }}>
                    <MathJax ref={mathJaxRef} style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',                            overflowY: 'clip' }} inline dynamic>
                        {sentence || ' '}
                        </MathJax>
                    </pre>
                </MathJaxContext>}
        </>
    )
}

export default PreviewMaths
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.